# Writing Files to a LAN server with a Web App in DMZ

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, io, lan, dmz

I have a ASP.NET application (C#), just a form for people to fill out and submit on the Internet. However, I need this application to write a file (just using IO) to a location on my LAN. This is a problem because of the DMZ.

From what I understand, the purpose of the DMZ is that no connections from the big scary Internet is allowed through to the LAN.

Internet ---> LAN: blocked
LAN ---> Internet: allowed
Internet ---> DMZ: Only certain ports
LAN ---> DMZ: allowed
DMZ ---> LAN: blocked

So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have NOTHING available from the DMZ --> LAN then about the only thing you can do is write the file locally and have a service in the LAN that polls for the files, copying them in when it finds them.  The polling routine could be as simple as a batch file running on a scheduled task that just blindly copies anything in a folder on the web server in the DMZ to a location internally.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "IF I have nothing" ?

Does that mean it's possible for the DMZ to connect to the LAN?

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  It's all dependent on how you configure the firewall.  It's very much possible to open ports allowing traffic initiated from the web server into the LAN.  In fact, it's possible to absolutely restrict traffic to the IP of the web server and to a specific IP internally so that it can ONLY communicate to that one server on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto squillman's, Yes, it is possible to have communication between DMZ back to the internal network (LAN). It all depends on the firewall rules configured at the Internal Firewall (that exists between the DMZ and the internal network). The firewall rules define the IP from, IP to, and the port.

Comment: Okay. So, lets say I have two Ports, A and B. Port A is on the server in the DMZ, it sends out information to the server in the LAN at port B. Do I have to configure my web application through the .config or any .aspx.cs forms to connect using these ports?

Comment: All computers run applications. A Client-Server Application goes a step further. If it is a Server application (of the Client-Server pair), it has ability to "listen to" a particular port in the same machine where it runs. If it is a Client application it has ability "talk to" a particular port of the machine running the Server application. It can be thought of as calling a toll free number, and talking to Support personnel at a particular Extension. In this analogy, the toll free phone is like your Server machine's IP, your phone is like Client IP and the port is like the Extension.

Comment: A firewall is a software/hardware/combination which exists between two networks. Typically, the firewall blocks ANY communication between source and destination computers (in different networks) ON ALL PORTS. The network administrator would configure some special rules on the firewall - a typical rule would be, ALLOW all communication from a particular Source (IP) to a particular Destination (IP) through a particular port. Different applications used different ports, for example, all HTTP typically happens through port 80, HTTPS through 443, telnet through 23, etc.